# Vue lazy loading still loading full javascript file

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to lazy load my Vuejs routes using this method:

```
const Foo = resolve => {
  // require.ensure is Webpack's special syntax for a code-split point.
  require.ensure(['./Foo.vue'], () => {
    resolve(require('./Foo.vue'))
  })
}
```

Along with web-pack code splitting. Which works  a treat as I can see the split files.

My webpack file:

```
module.exports = { 
    entry: './js/main.js',
    output: { 
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'../www/wp-content/themes/londoninter‌​nal/assets/js'), 
        publicPath: '../wp-content/themes/londoninternal/assets/js/', 
        filename: 'londoninternal.js',
    }
```

However, when I inspect the page and look in the network tab the site is still loading my full javascript file as well as the split javascript file.

How do I get my site to load only the split file that's needed at the time?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your logic when to load this chunk?

Comment: `module.exports = {
 entry: './js/main.js',
 output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname,'../www/wp-content/themes/londoninternal/assets/js'),
  publicPath: '../wp-content/themes/londoninternal/assets/js/',
  filename: 'londoninternal.js',
 },`

Thats my web pack set-up for the javascript ^ sorry I can't get it to format correctly in comments

Comment: Edit your question.